# Use 2 has_many relations or 2 HABTM?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have `Product` and `Categories` models.

Each Product can have many Categories. Each category will have many products.

Am I better off doing 2 `HABTM` or `has_many` relations?

I have been told that `HABTM` is being deprecated - is that true?

Also, for both, I assume I will have to use a join table `categories_products`. How do I create that? Just a regular migration?

Thanks.

Comment: As for me, I HATE HABTM! For many reasons, but first of all HABTM limits your logic space if you want to extend it. Imagine, you have to extend categories_products with smth like "purchases_count", to count which product has more or less sales within particular category. Or you want to have top 10 products of category etc... With HABTM you won't be able to make it easy.

Comment: So you are suggesting 2 has_many relations with a join table? FYI, I am going to want to do those stuff.

Comment: @marcamillion yes, the better way to go is to be verbose and write out the `has_many ..., through: ...` and `belongs_to` on each side of the association. Doing the `has_and_belongs_to_many` might save you some typing upfront, but **1.** It's less clear what's really going on and **2.** You lose flexibility.

Comment: 2 has_manys would be more reliable for development reasons and perspective.

Comment: I don't want to do `has_many :through` though. There is no middle model.

Comment: @ValeryKvon But, what about the join table? Would I still need a join table for 2 `has_many` relations?

Comment: @marcamillion You realize a habtm uses a 3rd table as the join table internally, right?

Comment: products has_many category_products, categories has_many category_products. CategoryProduct belongs_to product and category (two id fields and purchases_count as integer :) ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example of top(number). Updated.

```
    class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :category_products do
                def with_categories
                  includes(:category)
                end
              end
      has_many :categories, :through => :category_products

      def top_categories(number)
        category_products.with_categories.order("purchases_count DESC").limit(number).map {|c| c.category} # category included
      end

    end

    class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :category_products do
                def with_products
                  includes(:product)
                end
              end
      has_many :products, :through => :category_products

      def top_products(number)
        category_products.with_products.order("purchases_count DESC").limit(number).map {|c| c.product} # product included
      end

    end

    class CategoryProduct < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :product
      belongs_to :category

      validates_uniqueness_of :product_id, :scope => :category_id

      # attribute :purchases_count, :default => 0
    end
```

Comment: So if I do this, and then have `c = Category.first` What will `c.products` output? Will it output just the products that belong to that category?

Comment: Yes. just the products that belong to that category.

Comment: Btw, the comment `attribute :purchases_count, :default => 0`, can I actually write that in the comment? Or do I have do that in the migration?

Comment: Migration and/or add to DB table directly. Type:integer, default: 0